# Python Bottle multiple responses for one route

Tags: python, bottle

I'm looking for a way to send multiple responses for one route.
The problem is that from what I've read I have to return the content data.
For example :

```
@route('/events')
def positions():      
    for i in xrange(5):        
        response.content_type = 'text/event-stream'        
        response.set_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')                
        now = datetime.datetime.now().time().replace(microsecond=0)        
        return  "data: %s\n\n"%now
```

---

Is there a way to replace the last line in some function call, so I can send all the responses and then exit the route ?

Thanks,
Omer.

Comment: You can't do that. An HTTP request can only have one HTTP response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're asking so I might not be answering correctly, but would this do what you want?

```
@route('/events')
def positions():
    output = ''
    for i in xrange(5):
        now = datetime.datetime.now().time().replace(microsecond=0)
        output += "%s\n\n"%now
    response.content_type = 'text/event-stream'                
    response.set_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
    return "data: " + output
```